# Operator Overloading Post Decrement

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have to overload post decrement operator in which I have to Copy all elements of set1 into set2. After copying, decrement all elements of set1 (set2 = set1--;).
plzz tell me how can I implement this????
The simple post decrement operator I overloaded is as follows:

```
Set & operator --(int) 
    {
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            arr[i] --;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your postdecrement operator is wrong, it should not return reference to `*this`. As you can see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec its declaration is :

```
T T::operator--(int);
```

> Post-increment and post-decrement creates a copy of the object, increments or decrements the value of the object and returns the copy from before the increment or decrement.